# Import custom static library in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I created a static library in Swift and the goal is of course to distribute this and reuse this library in another project. In the project where I want to import this static library I do the following:

1. Drag xcode project from static library in Project Navigator
2. Drag xxxx.a (inside Products folder) to Build Phases > Link binaries with libraries
3. In the class where I want to use this library add: import MyStaticLib

Unfortunately I get an error saying: No such module 'MyStaticLib'.

But then when I create a new project in Xcode and do the exact same steps there's no error at all and I'm able to use the library in any class that imports this library. I looked at both project settings and can't seem to find anything weird.

Settings like Header Search Path and Library Search Path are empty in both projects.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you please tell how u fixed it ?